# PHPStorm on ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize shortcuts correctly

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

After reinstalling the system, PHPStorm sees a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

[image]

What I tried and check:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- PHPStorm Version 2021.2.3
- I see that there is a slash in the settings
- The layout is English and in the keyboard view, this is also a slash
- If I just press a key, it will be a slash, the problem is only in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- Recognizes other keys correctly
- I tried different keyboards
- The second shortcut through the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> slash works